# Acts As Taggable On

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm having problems getting the [acts-as-taggable-on gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) working properly.

I have a model:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable

end
```

I can add tags to it, and though its `tag_list` is populated:

```
$ a = ArchiveResource.new()
$ a.tag_list = ["one", "two", "three"]
$ a.tag_list # ["one", "two", "three"]
```

However, its `tag` association is not:

```
$ a.tags # []
```

If I check for all the tags, I can see they are being created:

```
$ ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "one">,
                            #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "two">,
                            #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 3, name: "three">
```

And if I check the model's `taggings` association I can see they exist there:

```
$ a.taggings #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "one">,
             #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "two">,
             #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 3, name: "three">
```

Looking more closely at a call to `a.tags.all` I can see from the query that there is a mismatch:

```
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = 1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'ArchiveResource' AND (taggings.context = ('tags'))
```

However the `taggings_context` of the model's Taggings are all set to `tag` *singular*, so the query always fails:

```
<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging id: 1, tag_id: 1, taggable_id: 1, taggable_type: "Resource", tagger_id: nil, tagger_type: nil, context: "tag", created_at: "2013-09-10 17:12:20
<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging id: 2, tag_id: 1, taggable_id: 1, taggable_type: "Resource", tagger_id: nil, tagger_type: nil, context: "tag", created_at: "2013-09-10 17:12:20
<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging id: 3, tag_id: 1, taggable_id: 1, taggable_type: "Resource", tagger_id: nil, tagger_type: nil, context: "tag", created_at: "2013-09-10 17:12:20
```

If I run through all the Taggables and set context to `tags`, everything works:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.all.each{|t|t.context = "tags"; t.save!}
```

**So why is this happening. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the default implementation is broken. By explicitly declaring the tags as `:tags` everything works OK:

```
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
```